# Inserting a blob via struct in jdbc (oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a sql datatype 'ty_order' which contains a few id's, string's etc ... and a *blob*. The datatype is used to avoid having a procedure head with 15+ parameters.

In java I do the following:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
OracleConnection c = ...;
OracleCallableStatement stmt = ... ;
StructDescriptor orderDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor('ty_order', c);

List<Object> elements = new ArrayList<Object>();

BLOB blob = new BLOB((OracleConnection) c, bytes.clone());
// put some other stuff into elements
elements.add(blob);

STRUCT order = new STRUCT(orderDescriptor, c, elements.toArray());

stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.BIGINT);
stmt.setSTRUCT(2, order);

stmt.execute();
```

The corresponding pl/sql procedure unpacks the struct and inserts everything into a table. However inserting the *blob* throws a SQLException my way:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24812: character set conversion to or from UCS2 failed
```

I've confirmed, that the cause for the exception is the inserting of the *blob*. Can anyone suggest a source for this error?

Comment: Showing the procedure code and the definition of `ty_order` might be useful.

Comment: Are you filling up other object's fields?

Comment: are you sure, that the target column is BLOB (and not CLOB)?